# Which one is right: "there are a lot of content" or "there is a lot of content"?

Tags: adjectives, uncountable-nouns

Which one is right?

1. There **are** a lot of content.
2. There **is** a lot of content.

A friend of mine said "there are a lot of content in TikTok app" and I corrected him saying "there is" which lead to an mini-argument and google searching. I tried doing my research and went through [this article](https://englishlessonsbrighton.co.uk/there-is-a-lot-of-vs-there-are-a-lot-of/) but it doesn't give the exact answer since [content](https://jakubmarian.com/content-vs-contents-in-english/) itself is a tricky word. So which one is right and why?

Comment: I think this is not a question about grammar, but about diplomacy. Your friend is just trying to save face. They know they shouldn't be arguing about a language they don't speak.  And they know that they don't speak it, it's not something they need to google. *Content* is not "a tricky word". Content is a very easy word. Content always is. Content never are. No exceptions. Very easy. Every two-year old speaker of the language knows that. And that is what's at the root of the argument. Your friend doesn't want to come off as knowing less than a two-year old. So be diplomatic. Or just let it go.

Comment: What? He’s grew up speaking english with his siblings and parents, and attending church sermons which were delivered in english... along with a british english education. So English is the primary language that he speaks all the time. And content is a tricky word—as explained in the article in the link in my question. My friend is open to learning new things and it was he who suggested checking it out online—I just happened to decide to ask here instead.

Comment: Hi, Saifur. In order to communicate with a user you need to use @ and the person's username e.g. @SaifurRahmanMohsin Sorry, but your friend just made a silly mistake that could have easily been missed at any other time. "There are a lot of content in X app" sounds wrong, and it *is* wrong. If the noun had been pluralised, i.e. "contents" then maybe your friend could have been excused for the slip up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer should be the 2nd option (*There **is** a lot of content in TikTok app.*) because the word "content" in this context is an uncountable noun.

There are also instances where the word "content" acts as a countable noun.
(Example: *The contents of the book are listed on the front page.*)

Check this [link](https://getproofed.com/writing-tips/word-choice-content-vs-contents/) for more clarification

Comment: What about ["The **contents** of which **are** unknown"](https://ludwig.guru/s/the+contents+of+which+are)?

Comment: `because the word "content" in this context is an uncountable noun.` But the OP has not provided any context!

Comment: I have edited my answer for more clarification.

Comment: I missed the TikTok reference, well spotted.

Comment: In 'The contents of the book are listed ...', 'contents is a **non-count** but plural form noun-form. One doesn't speak of '2 / 17 / half a dozen / several ... contents'.